# Creating new columns in pandas based on conditions satisfied by the columns using functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have several columns in a pandas data frame. Based on each one of the columns, I need to create a new column. This function works:

```
def f(row):
    if row['col_1'] == 0:
        val = 'Neutral'
    elif row['col_1'] > 0:
        val = 'Growth'
    else:
        val = 'Contraction'
    return val

df['New_Col_1'] = df.apply(f(row) , axis=1)
```

But since I have several columns for comparison (col_2, col_3 etc), I want to pass the name of the column as a parameter in the function.

```
def f(row,col_name):
    if row[col_name] == 0:
        val = 'Neutral'
    elif row[col_name] > 0:
        val = 'Growth'
    else:
        val = 'Contraction'
    return val

df['New_Col_1'] = df.apply(f(row,'col_1') , axis=1)
```

But, there is an error. It says parameter 'row' is not defined. How do I overcome this?

Comment: You're missing a `lambda` function : `df.apply(lambda row: f(row,'col_1') , axis=1)`

Comment: This works. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The df.apply() is missing a lambda function as mentioned in a comment.

```
def f(row,col_name):
    if row[col_name] == 0:
        val = 'Neutral'
    elif row[col_name] > 0:
        val = 'Growth'
    else:
        val = 'Contraction'
    return val

df['New_Col_1'] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row,'col_1') , axis=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out `df.loc[]`, it takes two paramters which you can think of as row-spec and column-spec, so you'd use it like this:

```
df['New_Col_1'] = 'Contraction' # Default, to be overwritten below
df.loc[df['col_1'] == 0, 'New_Col_1'] = 'Neutral'
df.loc[df['col_1'] > 0, 'New_Col_1'] = 'Growth'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **df.loc[condition, column_name] = value** to filter a df and write a new value:

```
df['New_Col_1'] = None # initial
df.loc[df.col1==0, 'New_Col_1'] = 'Neutral'
df.loc[df.col1>0, 'New_Col_1'] = 'Growth'
df.loc[df.col1<0, 'New_Col_1'] = 'Contraction'
```